# Шуази — какой род?

Tags: существительные

Думаю, мужского, по аналогии с колли.

Comment: Мне очень хочется знать, что это за порода собак — **шуази**. Не знаю такой. Просветите меня, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пять с половиной лет вопросу. Я уже не помню

Comment: Странно, что Вы не помните породу собаки, про которую задавали вопрос. Думаю, что Вы ошиблись. Нет такой породы. Есть шпиц с кличкой **Шуази** Рич Де Ви С Отрадного Двора (и другие животные со словом "Шуази"). https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%86+%D0%A8%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8&biw=1366&bih=657&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=7Kq9F7WzsURUSM%253A%252C3IrRRLclU0forM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTT4fUsQMi22n-xF8iEime0Ms_QqQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR34q-kKroAhWlpYsKHQSGB7kQ9QEwAHoECAkQBQ#imgrc=dlL1lR2off_ikM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По аналогии с "колли" и "колибри", слово "шуази" должно быть общего рода, то есть сочетаться как с мужским, так и с женским родом.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря о чём или о ком  речь. Огюст Шуази - муж. Женщины рода Шуази - женский. Пляж Шуази, муниципалитет Шуази во Франции - муж. Есть биолог Шуази. А Вы о чём?

Несклоняемые существительные, обозначающие одушевленные предметы (кроме лиц), относятся к мужскому роду, например: зебу, пони, шимпанзе, какаду, кенгуру, фламинго, макао, нанду, коала, жако. При этом мужской род употребляется безотносительно к полу животного. Однако если контекст указывает на самку, то соответствующие слова употребляются в форме женского рода, например:

кенгуру несла в сумке кенгуренка, шимпанзе кормила детёныша.

http://revolution.allbest.ru/pedagogics/00331765_0.html

Comment: о породе собак

Comment: зависит от того, кто это - самка или самец.